Замер громкости звука в реальном времени C/C++
Помогите или дайте подсказку, нужно что бы программа каждый заданный промежуток времени замеряла громкость звука поступающего на микрофон
и отображала его численно, например минимальный звук 0, а максимальный 250

Под какую ОС? И 250 - это в каких единицах?

Под windows 10, 250 это в условных единицах, но можно в децибелах

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/coreaudio/wasapi

Вам необходим специальный прибор - шумомер. С обычным микрофоном посредством обычных API для работы с аудио сделать этого толком не получится.

Peak Meters умеют возвращать максимальную громкость за период измерения: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/peak-meters

Вот прям в С++ такое не встроено. Но в большинстве операционных систем есть подсистемы для работы с аудио и соответственно библиотеки.
И вот, например, bass.dll есть для нескольких ОС, и она обеспечивает работу с нативными средствами ( DirectSound в Windows, CoreAudio в MacOS, не знаю чего там в Android)

Я делал так:
открывал устройство захвата (микрофон) в формате PCM, MONO, 8bit unsigned, 8000kHz.
читал с него 1000 байт. вычитал минимум из максимума. 0-тишина, 255-100%
Если вместо PCM ставите U-Law или A-Law то шкала будет растянута по соотвествующим законам. На слух очень похожа на громкость речи.
Если нужен логарифм в дБ то нормируйте к 1 и считайте логорифм.

Оно так не работает. Диапазон PCM audio в этом случае всегда 0...255 вне зависимости от громкости записанного звука. Ну и воспроизводить это PCM audio тоже можно с произвольной громкостью. Необходимо, как минимум, учитывать характеристики микрофона, хотя бы ориентироваться, какая громкость звука соответствует минимому сигнала и на какой достигается максимум, а еще лучше АЧХ, так как эти параметры сильно зависят от частоты звука.

Это аудио не воспроизводится, а записывается. С громкостью заданной пользователем.  Тс нужны условные попугаи. Какая ещё АХЧ?))
